# Characters break while using php mkdir

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a directory with persian characters using `php mkdir`.

When I use `mkdir` width this string: `ساده`, the created directory is something like `Ø³Ø§Ø¯Ù‡`.

Again, when I'm trying to access this directory, it's ok and `php` will find this and it seems this characters are not human readable.

I tried `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` but didn't work.

Do you have any experience about this situation and would you please help me to fix this?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: mkdir on what OS? you're simply assuming that your OS's filesystem uses UTF for the filenames...

Comment: @MarcB I'm using xamp server in windows 7 and I'm sure my system is using utf for filenames.

Comment: Check if your php file is in UTF-8 charset too. you may have to add a BOM.

Comment: It looks like your system is interpreting the file name as Windows-1252 when it should be interpreted as UTF-8. You can see that `mb_convert_encoding ("ساده", "UTF-8", "Windows-1252")` gives `"Ø³Ø§Ø¯Ù‡"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the encoding of your php file. It should be utf8. Are you using nodepad or a code editor?. Make sure the character encoding of the editor is set to utf8